# MyStudio Page missing altogether from Aptana 3.0.3

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I recently downloaded and installed Aptana Studio 3.0.3. I noticed upon opening the program that the MyStudio page was nowhere to be found. I tried going to Preferences->Aptana->Startup, but that doesn't exist in the menu. I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and downloaded the Aptana x64 package. Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

That page was gone. It will reappear in 3.0.4.